# How to create and Increment composite Key : EntityFramework core

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, composite-key

I have two objects Recipe and Site

I want to get a value auto incremented called counter in Recipe based on siteId using Entity framework 5.0

Exemple of result and current code :

```
Recipe 1 : siteId :1 | counter = 1 
Recipe 2 : siteId :1 | counter = 2 
Recipe 3 : siteId :2 | counter = 1
Recipe 4 : siteId :1 | counter = 3

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().Property(s => s.Id)
                                 .UseIdentityColumn(seed: 1000, increment: 1).HasColumnName("Id");
   modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>(s => s.UseTemporalTable());
   modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().HasAlternateKey(o => new { o.Order, o.SiteId })
                                .HasName("counter");
   modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().Property(o => o.Order)
                                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasColumnName("Order").HasDefaultValueSql("1");
}

public class Recipe : AbstractModel
{
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public int? OrderBySite { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public DateTime RecipeCreationDateTime { get; set; }
        public Site Site { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SiteId")]
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
} 

public class Site : AbstractModel
{
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
} 

public abstract class AbstractModel
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Error when I'm trying to add new recipe :

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderBySite', table
> 'StockProject2.dbo.Recipes'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
> fails. The statement has been terminated.

**UPDATED 01: code throwing exeption :**
When I add a recipe, the entity go through the function :

```
 public async override Task<ActionResult<API.Recipe>> AddRecipe([FromBody] API.Recipe body)
        {      
            body.RecipeCreationDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            MODEL.Recipe recipe = await _recipeService.AddAsync(_mapper.Map<MODEL.Recipe>(body));
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<API.Recipe>(recipe));
        }
```

```
 new Recipe value : siteId :1000 | order = 0 | counter = null
```

### --> the exeption is thrown by counter, but I though counter should be fill by my rule writed in the model builder.

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().HasKey(o => new { o.Order, o.SiteId }).HasName("counter");
       modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().Property(o => o.Order).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasColumnName("Order").HasDefaultValueSql("1");
```

**UPDATED 02: object throwing exeption  :** At line :   `await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();` the entity **recipe** has value for counter = **null**, order = **null**
Do I have to handle myself the counter or the order value?  I though ( is it the case ?) EF should auto fill with the rules, but it's not the case.

```
 public async virtual Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                entity = (await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity)).Entity;
                await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StringBuilder erreurMsg = new StringBuilder("\n");
                erreurMsg.AppendLine($"Function : {nameof(AddAsync)}");
                erreurMsg.AppendLine($"Parameters : {nameof(entity)} = {JsonSerializer.Serialize(entity)}");
                erreurMsg.AppendLine($"Erreur: { ex }");
                _logger.LogError(erreurMsg.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show the code that throws the exception.

Comment: @GertArnold I added the code that throws the exception, hope you could help me in my understanding.

Comment: This is all highly confusing. In the first place, `counter`is not a field but an index name, so I don't see how `counter = 1` etc. is related. Also, the code you show doesn't show the content of objects that are inserted.  *Seemingly* you expect that `Order` and `SiteId` are auto-incremented. There's no reason to expect that.

Comment: The goal of this is to get a counter by site for the recipe, 
I though that writting my rule  in the modelBuilder, like I did in past for sequence or ComputedColumn would increment the number of the counter and in this specifique case, also auto generate a new counter if need.
I 'm gonna add an exemple of the object in the thread.